# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on property access, (OS X 10.8.5)

Tags: macos, memory-management, properties, exc-bad-access, ivar

I'm using an autosynthesized `@property`. When I access the property in a method, I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception. Here's are the relevant sections of code from my implementation file:

```
#import "BBBluetoothController.h"
#import <IOBluetooth/IOBluetooth.h>

@interface BBBluetoothController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *bluetoothManager;

@end

@implementation BBBluetoothController

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] init];
        _bluetoothManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] init];
        _bluetoothManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (IBAction)startScanning:(id)sender {
    if (self.bluetoothManager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        [self.bluetoothManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        self.isScanning = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

The exception is thrown in `-startScanning:` on the first line of the method. Drilling down in the stack trace, I see the exception is thrown from inside the `CBCentralManager`'s implementation:

`0x7fff96c6ed49:  leaq   -413178944(%rip), %rax    ; CBCentralManager._delegate`

If I break in `-startScanning:` I can see the following in `lldb`:

```
(lldb) po self
<BBBluetoothController: 0x1022213b0>
(lldb) po self.bluetoothManager
<CBConcreteCentralManager: 0x102222180>
(lldb) p self.bluetoothManager.state
(CBCentralManagerState) $2 = CBCentralManagerStateUnknown
(lldb) po self.bluetoothManager.delegate
<BBBluetoothController: 0x1022213b0>
```

Furthermore, if I refer to the instance variable in `-startScanning:` instead of the property, everything runs without a hitch. Am I missing something obvious here?

**Edit:**

For what it's worth, this works just fine on OS X 10.9, but not OS X 10.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops! Wasn't using the designated initializer: `-[CBCentralManager initWithDelegate:queue:]`.